# Why isn't my compound query working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble getting the query I am working on to execute correctly. I have two tables and need the sum of certian columns in one table, but only need to sum numbers for certain rows based on flags that are set in another table. The query is as follows:

```
    SELECT (SUM(`jan_2014`) FROM `balances`  
             JOIN `locations`  AS `January 2014`, 
           (SUM(`feb_2014`) FROM `loan_balances`  
            JOIN `locations`  AS `February 2014`, 
           (SUM(`mar_2014`) FROM `loan_balances`  
             JOIN `locations`  AS `March 2014`,
   WHERE `loan_type` = 'payday' 
   AND `district_manager` = 'Melissa Lutz' 
   AND `store_name` = 'Marietta' 
   AND `fast_cash` = ‘0’ 
   AND `urgent_cash` = “0”
```

The numeric data is in table labeled "balances", and the flags for the rows I need is in table labeled  "Locations", both in the same database labeled "Joe".

Comment: I'm missing the question, current results (or error messsages) and desired results.

Comment: You've got no `JOIN` criteria, you've got `SUM()` outside of `SELECT` statements, single quotes and double quotes mixed together.  Cat's and dogs living together.

Comment: What columns do you use to join the `locations` table with `balances` and `loan_balances` tables? Which table do the columns `jan_2014`, etc. come from?

Comment: The error I get in Sequel when I run the query is as follows:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `balances`  
             JOIN `locations`  AS `January 2014`, 
           ' at line 1

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would get you an answer.

Comment: You really need to study how to write queries... your syntax is simply wrong, there's no way to know how `loan_balances` and `locations` are related... and there's no way to help you if you don't post a data sample.

Comment: I am completely new to using sql, so I understand that the current query is chaos, which is why I am asking here! How are the sum statements outside SELECT statements? and what JOIN criteria am i missing? thank you in advance for your help! I am working on sample data to post. @Goat CO

Comment: I'm not sure how to post sample data on here, but I have a column labeled "city" in the locations table, and a column labeled "store" in the balances table that are related, having the same data in the rows, which is the name of the city the store is in.   The desired results are the sum of the column for a certain month based on flag columns in the Locations table for each store. @Barranka

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful for the help, although as a REALLY new stackoverflow user I made a mess of posting this question. The most helpful comment was that I need to study how to write queries. I did just that after posting this question and coming up short on the help I needed. I did come up with the answer. the query needed to look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(a.jan_2014), SUM(a.feb_2014), SUM(a.mar_2014), SUM(a.apr_2014) , SUM(a.may_2014) , SUM(a.jun_2014) FROM balances a INNER JOIN Locations b ON a.store_name=b.city WHERE product_type = 'pay' AND district_manager = 'Mel Lantz'  AND fast_cash = '0' AND urgent_cash = '1'
```

where I can check the fast_cash and urgent_cash flags conditionally in my code to determine which rows in the date columns I want the sum of.